# React Routing gives Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-component

I am trying to create routes for my React application with react-router-component. But when I build my project with webpack, I get the error:

`ERROR in ./app/js/client.jsx
Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: Line 22: Unexpected token <`

The routes are in my client.jsx file, which looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router-component');
var Locations = Router.Locations;
var Location = Router.Location;
var {MainPage} = require('./components/views/app.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Locations>
        <Location path="/" handler={MainPage} />
      </Locations>
    )
  }
})

React.render(React.createElement(App), document.body)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Edit: my webpack configuration looks like this:

```
webpack: {
  client: {
    entry: __dirname + '/app/js/client.jsx',
    output: {
      path: 'build/',
      file: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader:'jsx-loader'
      }]
    }
  },
  test: {
    entry: __dirname + '/test/client/test.js',
    output: {
      path: 'test/client/',
      file: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader:'jsx-loader'
      }]
    }
  },
  karma_test: {
    entry: __dirname + '/test/karma_tests/test_entry.js',
    output: {
      path: 'test/karma_tests/',
      file: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader:'jsx-loader'
      }]
    },
    background: true
  }
},
```

You can see the full project so far here: https://github.com/mrbgit/short-stories/tree/add-category-age

Comment: Presumably your JSX isn't being compiled. What Webpack loader are you using to compile it? Can you edit your question to include your Webpack configuration?

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I added the webpack configuration and a link to the branch of my github repo with the full project so far.

Comment: I think I might have been mistaken. Have other JSX files been working? The error message is odd, since `client.jsx` doesn't appear to have 22 lines, so it seems like this is happening after the file is compiled (since the compiled output probably has 22+ lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use destructuring for the `MainPage` variable since that file is only exporting the React class. It should look like this

```
var MainPage = require('./components/views/app.jsx');
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Ballot that was it!